# Error connecting to MySQL in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp

I have created this simple PHP code for a login page

```
<head>
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
        <form method=POST>
            <table>
                <tr><th>UserName</th>
                    <td><input type=text name=user></input></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Password</th>
                    <td><input type=password name=pass></input></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Phone Number</th>
                    <td><input type=text name=phone></input></td></tr>
                <tr><th>Email</th>
                    <td><input type=text name=email></input></td></tr>
                <tr><th>City</th>
                    <td><input type=text name=city></input></td></tr>
                <tr><td><input type=submit name=submit value=Submit></input></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['user']))
        {
            if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,40}$/",$_POST['user']))
                {
                    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}$/",$_POST['pass']))
                        {
                            if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                                {
                                    if(preg_match("/[0-9]{10}/",$_POST['phone']))
                                        {
                                            $username=$_POST['user'];
                                            $password=$_POST['pass'];
                                            $Email=$_POST['email'];
                                            $phoneNumber=$_POST['phone'];
                                            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:8080","root","","user");
                                            mysqli_query($con,"insert into user values('$username','$Email','$phoneNumber','$city')");

                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            echo "Invalid Phone number";
                                        }
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                        echo "Invalid Email";
                                }
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                echo "Invalid Phone number";
                            }
                }

                else
                    {
                        echo "Invalid user";
                    }

        }

?>
```

Whenever i run this script and try to insert values into the tables, it takes a lot of time and throws the following error/Warning. I have not changed the username and password and i believe by default it is root and blank.

> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 39
>
> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=4708 in C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 39
>
> **Warning**: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 39
>
> **Fatal error**: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\home.php on line 39

Could someone help me with this as i believe that the problem lies with some of the port configuration.

Thanks and regards.

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)? When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Instead of writing your own login system, you should probably be using a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that comes with an [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in. What you've concocted here is not suitable for production use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, connecting to DB using XAMPP doesn't require you to specify the port. Replace `localhost:8080` with `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

yo can increase  Maximum execution time if you sure that your code is correct.
this time is in php.ini config file

```
; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 30
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the edited script.
Try to run that. Also make sure mysql is working properly.
    
        Login Page
    
    
            
                
                    UserName
                        
                    Password
                        
                    Phone Number
                        
                    Email
                        
                    City

```
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    set_time_limit (0);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['user']))
        {
            if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]{3,40}$/",$_POST['user']))
                {
                    if(preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,20}$/",$_POST['pass']))
                        {
                            if(filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
                                {
                                    if(preg_match("/[0-9]{10}/",$_POST['phone']))
                                        {
                                            $username=$_POST['user'];
                                            $password=$_POST['pass'];
                                            $Email=$_POST['email'];
                                            $phoneNumber=$_POST['phone'];
                                            $con=mysqli_connect("localhost:8080","root","","user");
                                            mysqli_query($con,"insert into user values('$username','$Email','$phoneNumber','$city')");

                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            echo "Invalid Phone number";
                                        }
                                }
                            else
                                {
                                        echo "Invalid Email";
                                }
                        }
                        else
                            {
                                echo "Invalid Phone number";
                            }
                }

                else
                    {
                        echo "Invalid user";
                    }

        }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't have to specify the port number 8080 along with the localhost. simply use localhost instead