# PHP cant connect to MySql (MySqli)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to simply connect to a MySQL database on my localhost With php and mysqli. But I'm encountering a problem.

I Wrote the code below

```
<?php
$sql = new mysqli('127.0.0.1:777','root','Qwert12345','plot_io_db');
//echo $sql->query('Select * From players');
?>
```

Assuming that all the information is correct (there is a MySQL server running and it includes a database with the name 'plot_io_db' and username and the password are correct), it still takes ages for the script to return results and it returns the following result

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\default.php on line 2
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=11092 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\default.php on line 2
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\default.php on line 2
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\default.php on line 2
```

My question is: Why does this happen and how to solve this.

P.S: I commented the third line just to bring the result time below ten minutes!

Comment: Is your DB port 777?

Comment: Try `localhost:777`

Comment: Here are som hints based on your error message: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error connecting to MySQL in XAMPP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589473/error-connecting-to-mysql-in-xampp)

Comment: @rollstuhlfahrer - that's not true. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19712307/mysql-localhost-127-0-0-1

Comment: although I don't believe that's the issue here.  probably either a port issue or a php execution timeout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$sql = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','Qwert12345','plot_io_db');
//echo $sql->query('Select * From players');
?>
```

It will work. Just remove port from localhost (127.0.0.1)